# Where is the setting file(like .bashrc) for bash in win10?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just setting WSL on win10 and modify the text/background color.
How can i backup the setting file like ubuntu .bashrc file?

[image: my setting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Subsystem for Linux uses Windows' Command Prompt as a front-end. To change the background you need to change the background of Command prompt which will change background colors for all instances of Command Prompt. However, you can change the color of the text color by simply editing `.bashrc` file located in `/home/username/.bashrc`.

So, backing up the settings for Command Prompt makes it a Windows question which I believe is off-topic here for which you can use [Super User - Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com) or read [Where are the default settings saved for the Command prompt defaults? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/683431)